# Sublime Text 3 - Clean Paste

Tags: python, sublimetext3

Sublime Text 3 is looking great, but one item that is keeping me from switching is the compatibility of [Clipboard Commands](https://github.com/SublimeText/ClipboardCommands). The only thing I use this plugin for is the "clean_paste" function which basically makes pasting copied content from Microsoft Word (or any other text editor) strip out the funny characters it normally comes with. Does anyone know of a native function that ST3 provides that I can map a keybinding to? Here is what ClipboardCommand does (in the ST2 version):

```
class ClipboardCommandsPastePlainText(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        copy(clean_paste(clipboard()))
        self.view.run_command('paste')
```

Possibly more of a Python question in general as well, but you can also create your own keybindings and this one basically just references that command:

```
"caption": "Clipboard: Paste Plain Text",
"command": "clipboard_commands_paste_plain_text"
```

So if the `command` is something I could just put that function into that'd be great, but not sure how that works in Python. Thanks for any help!

Comment: All you have to do is fix `clean_copy` and `clean_paste`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question

Comment: To clarify, I'd love to port over this ST2 plugin to ST3, but not being a Python dev, I was wondering if someone knew the best way to map a new key binding in Sublime (which I know how to do), but reference that function that does the `clean_paste` into it instead of referencing a Class definition as it is does originally. Or, if this makes the question clearer, a how I could perform a clean paste from Miscrosoft Word into ST3 (so I can get rid of all the "special/encoded  characters"

Comment: All commands must reference a class name. Sorry. That's a pretty small plugin - it should be pretty straightforward to port

Comment: So - part question, but more a call to action for someone who may be up to getting this ST3 compatible.

Comment: Your understanding of SublimeText commands is lacking. To make this plugin work in SublimeText3, you'd need to port the `clean_paste` function to python3, which could probably be done with `2to3` as it doesn't seem complicated - the class itself is fine. But I also don't see a valid question here: if it's "can someone port this to ST3" this would be off topic, ask on the ST forums. A better question would be "can you help me port this to ST3", but this would require you to try something first. Right now it just reads like you just want someone to do work for you for a few internet points...

Comment: Agree the ST forums would be a better place for this type of request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not too much work to make this python 3 compatible:

```
# coding=utf8
import sublime_plugin, sublime, re, html

def clipboard():
    return sublime.get_clipboard()

def copy(data):
    sublime.set_clipboard(data)

# to transfer data to sublime text
def clean_paste(data):
    # clean word
    data = str(data)
    data = data.replace(u'”', '"').replace(u'“', '"').replace(u'’', "'")
    data = data.replace('________________________________________', '\n')
    # clean htmlentities
    data = re.sub('&([^;]+);', lambda m: unichr(html.entities.name2codepoint[m.group(1)]), data)
    return data;

# to transfer data from sublime text
def clean_copy(data):
    # clean html
    data = str(data)
    data = re.sub(r'<br ?/?>', '\n', data, re.I);
    data = re.sub(r'<[^>]*>', '', data);
    # clean htmlentities
    data = re.sub('&([^;]+);', lambda m: unichr(html.entities.name2codepoint[m.group(1)]), data)
    return data;
```

I've forked the linked plugin and uploaded the changes [here](https://github.com/Noelkd/ClipboardCommands)

Tested it in sublime3 and it appears to work, but without test cases I'll leave that one to you.

Comment: Sorry about that, had abandoned the post and was going to post it on the forums - thanks for this!